# IF IS nothing then count

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I want to create statement such as

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value)),0,(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)/1)
```

but from some reason it does not work. It should check value if it is null. If it's null, just enter 0, if it is not null, just make the calculation.

What am I doing wrong here? I am getting error for the first part of "IsNothing" code which says `"Wrong number of arguments"` but I do not see the error.

Comment: Pff, I see it now.. I missed the brackets behind "IIF" and in the end.. Gosh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

```
=IIf((IsNothing(Fields!Amount.Value)),0,(Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)/1))
```

Just missed brackets.